# GetIpAddrTable throws a stack fault

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

Can anyone explain why this code throws an exception at the first call to GetIpAddrTable? The run time library complains of heap corruption.
The first call after a reboot works but therefter it doesn't.

```
#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

BOOL GetMyIPAddress(LPVOID addressBuffer) {
    int i;
    BOOL result = FALSE;
    IN_ADDR loopbackSubnet = { 0 }, loopbackNetwork = { 0 };
    IN6_ADDR ipv6Loopback;
    ZeroMemory(&ipv6Loopback, sizeof(IN6_ADDR));

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.0.0", &loopbackSubnet);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &loopbackNetwork);
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &ipv6Loopback);

    /* Variables used by GetIpAddrTable */
    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)MALLOC(sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE));
    if (pIPAddrTable)
    {
        DWORD dwSize = 0;
        ZeroMemory(pIPAddrTable, dwSize);
        DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
        IN_ADDR IPAddr = { 0 };

        /* Variables used to return error message */
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;
        // Make an initial call to GetIpAddrTable to get the
        // necessary size into the dwSize variable
        if (GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, FALSE) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
            FREE(pIPAddrTable);
            pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)MALLOC(dwSize);
            if (pIPAddrTable == NULL) {
                printf("Memory allocation failed for GetIpAddrTable\n");
                return FALSE;
            }
            else {
                ZeroMemory(pIPAddrTable, dwSize);
                // Make a second call to GetIpAddrTable to get the
                // actual data we want
                dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, FALSE);
                if (dwRetVal != NO_ERROR) {
                    printf("GetIpAddrTable failed with error %d\n", dwRetVal);
                    if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwRetVal, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),       // Default language
                        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL)) {
                        _RPT1(_CRT_WARN, "\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
                        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
                for (i = 0; i < (int)pIPAddrTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
                    IPAddr.S_un.S_addr = (u_long)pIPAddrTable->table[i].dwAddr;
                    if (((IPAddr.S_un.S_addr & loopbackSubnet.S_un.S_addr) ^ (loopbackNetwork.S_un.S_addr & loopbackSubnet.S_un.S_addr)) != 0)
                    {
                        ((IN_ADDR*)addressBuffer)->S_un.S_addr = IPAddr.S_un.S_addr;
                        result = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                FREE(pIPAddrTable);
                pIPAddrTable = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It was lifted from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getipaddrtable

Comment: You are pre-allocating the buffer and passing it as a non-null memory pointer to `GetIpAddrTable()`, but you are initializing `dwSize` to 0 instead of the size you allocated. Your code doesn't exactly match Microsoft's example, but on the other hand Microsoft's example has the same bug as your code

Comment: I have tried it both ways as well and neither works. i.e. if I pass in a NULL buffer with dwSize 0, an allocated structure with dwSize set to the size. and MS's approach of an allocated buffer with dwSize 0! I am wondering if the structure is changing as I am doing JUPnP discovery in a different thread

Comment: Do you have the same problem with [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses)?

Comment: Hmm - so running it in my winmain function before the other threads fire up it works fine! So will code it that way....

Comment: There is nothing wrong with threads querying the OS for information.  So, unless this is actually a bug in `GetIpAddrTable()` itself, then something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - think I have sorted this out. Was an issue elsewhere - I hate debugging services!